# Multiple bar charts in one graph in Octave

Tags: matlab, histogram, bar-chart, octave

Using Octave 4.2.1 on Windows with the `qt` graphics toolkit (I can't use `gnuplot` because it crashes in some other part of the code). I have a dataset which is 35x7x4 (35 data points for 7 conditions on 4 channels) - you can use random data for the purpose of this exercise.

I am trying to create 4 subplots (1 for each channel), with 7 bar graphs on each subplot (one per condition) to see how the distribution of data changes with each condition. Each of the 7x4 = 28 distributions has its own set of bins and frequencies, and I can't seem to be able to combine the 7 datasets on one graph (subplot).

Posting the whole of the code would be too complicated, but here's a simplified version:

```
nb_channels = 4;
nb_conditions = 7;
nbins = 15;
freq = zeros(nbins,nb_conditions,nb_channels);
xbin = zeros(nbins,nb_conditions,nb_channels);

plot_colours = [91 237 165 255 68 112 255;
  155 125 165 192 114 173 0;
  213 49 165 0 196 71 255];
plot_colours = plot_colours / 255;

for k = 1:nb_channels
  for n = 1:nb_conditions
    % some complex calculations to generate temp variable
    [freq(:,n,k),xbin(:,n,k)] = hist(temp,nbins);
  end
end

figure
for k = 1:nb_channels
  subplot(2,2,k)
  for n = 1:nb_conditions
    bar(xbin(:,n,k),freq(:,n,k),'FaceColor',plot_colours(:,n))
    hold on
  end
  hold off
  legend('condition #1','condition #2','condition #3','condition #4','condition #5','condition #6','condition #7')
end
```

which gives something like this:

[image]

So you can't really see anything, all the bars are on top of each other. In addition, Octave doesn't support transparency property for patch objects (which is what bar charts use), so I can't overlay the histograms on top of each other, which I would really quite like to do.

Is there a better way to approach this? It seems that `bar` will only accept a vector for x data and not a matrix, so I am stuck in having to use `hold on` and loop through the various conditions, instead of using a matrix approach.

Comment: the reason it looks messy is because the location of the bars is different. Can you not make sure that all the bars of different plots are centered in the same place? That would make a plot with overlayed bars.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The problem is that the bins are different for each condition, they are calculated by the `hist` function. I guess I could specify a common set of bins to all conditions. I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant. I know this may not be the desired functionality, but it may not matter. Depends on you I guess

Comment: What is wrong with line plots? Why do you need bar plots? Bars are not really meant to display multiple series in the same graph, no matter how you solve it, it always ends up being more confusing than necessary. A set of line plots is always the better approach to compare various series.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Point taken. I guess distributions are generally plotted as bar graphs (unless you are actually fitting a probability law onto it, e.g. with `histfit`) and it's kind of what the people I will be sharing the plots with expect. Having said that, I will definitely also try the line plot approach to see if it can convey the results in a better manner.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530944/octave-creating-two-histograms-with-color-blending) is a workaround that works with gnuplot toolkit. You can use `graphics_toolkit` function to switch between different graphics toolkits.  Also [it seems](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/7dd3ab97ccd5) that there is an initial implementation of alpha transparency in Octave 4.4

Comment: I have posted an answer with the various suggestions - thank you all. Good to know that alpha transparency is coming up in Octave 4.4.

Comment: Octave 4.4 has been [released.](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/news/release/2018/04/30/octave-4.4.0-released.html)

Comment: @rahnema1 thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I'll try to answer my own question based on the suggestions made in the comments:

### Suggestion 1: make all the bins the same

This does improve the results somewhat but it's still an issue due to the lack of transparency for patch objects.

Code changes:

```
nbins = 15;
xbin = linspace(5.8,6.5,nbins);

for k = 1:nb_channels
  for n = 1:nb_conditions
    % some complex calculations to generate temp variable
    freq_flow(:,n,k) = hist(temp,xbin);
  end
end

figure
for k = 1:nb_channels
  subplot(2,2,k)
  for n = 1:nb_conditions
    bar(xbin,freq_flow(:,n,k),'FaceColor',plot_colours(:,n))
    hold on
  end
  hold off
  xlim([5.8 6.3])
  legend('condition #1','condition #2','condition #3','condition #4','condition #5','condition #6','condition #7')
end
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

### Suggestion 2: Use line plots instead of bar charts

This helps a bit more in terms of readability. However, the result is a bit "piece-wise".

Code changes:

```
 figure
    for k = 1:nb_channels
      subplot(2,2,k)
      for n = 1:nb_conditions
        plot(xbin,freq_flow(:,n,k),'LineStyle','none','marker','.',...
            'markersize',12,'MarkerEdgeColor',plot_colours(:,n),...
            'MarkerFaceColor',plot_colours(:,n))
        hold on
      end
      hold off
      xlim([5.8 6.3])
      legend('condition #1','condition #2','condition #3','condition #4','condition #5','condition #6','condition #7')
    end
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

The legend is a bit screwed but I can probably sort that out.

A variation on this I also tried was to plot just the points as markers, and then a fitted normal distribution on top. I won't post all the code here, but the result looks something like this:

[image]

### Suggestion 3: transparency workaround with gnuplot

Unfortunately, before I even got to the transparency workaround, `gnuplot` keeps crashing when trying to plot the figure. There's something it doesn't like with subplots and legends I think (which is why I moved to `qt` graphics toolkit in the first place, as I had exactly the same issue in other parts of the code).

### Solution 4: use 3D bar graph

I found this on SO: [3D histogram with gnuplot or octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180890/3d-histogram-with-gnuplot-or-octave)

and used it as such:

```
figure
for k = 1:size(flow_factor,2)
  subplot(2,2,k)
  h = my_bar3(freq_flow(:,:,k));
  fvcd = kron((1:numel(freq_flow(:,:,k)))', ones(6,1));
  set(h, 'FaceVertexCData',fvcd, 'FaceColor','flat', 'CDataMapping','scaled')
  colormap hsv; axis tight; view(50,25)
  ylbl = cell(length(xbin),1);
  for k=1:length(xbin)
    ylb{k} = num2str(xbin(k));
  end
  set(gca,'YTick',1:2:nbins);
  set(gca,'YTickLabel',ylb(1:2:end));
end
```

to produce:

[image]

Which isn't bad, but probably not as clear as the line plots.

### Conclusion

On balance, I will probably end up using one of the line plots approaches, as they tend to be clearer.